# MongoDB query - Match, lookup, then?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Fairly new to MongoDB.  I have one collection called `maProps` that holds documents similar to:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(18),
    "custom_branding" : false,
    "dashboard_rating" : true,
    "ideas_forum" : true,
    "membership_domain_restricted" : true
}
```

I first want to find all documents in the collection that has a false value for `custom_branding` or that `custom_branding` doesn't exist on the document

```
db.getCollection('maProps').aggregate(
        [
          {$match: {custom_branding: {$ne: false}}}, ......
```

I have another collection called `bFeatures` that holds documents similar to:

```
{
    "_id" : "feature_1_I_want",
    "masterAccounts" : [
        {
            "masterAccountId" : NumberLong(1),
            "available" : true,
            "enabled" : true
        },
        {
            "masterAccountId" : NumberLong(12),
            "available" : false,
            "enabled" : false
        },
        {
            "masterAccountId" : NumberLong(13),
            "available" : false,
            "enabled" : false
        },.......
}
```

So I believe my next step in the script would be to add a `$lookup` to join

```
            {$lookup: 
                {
                    from: 'betaFeature',
                    LocalField: '_id',
                    foreignField: '',
                    as: "beta",
```

Trying to accomplish:
I essentially would like to first find all `masterAccounts` in `maProps` that have a `custom_branding` of false or field doesn't exist.  Then using that information of master accounts, go to `bFeatures`, find an `_id` that matches `feature_1_I_want`, all the `masterAccounts` we matched in `maProps` - add them to the collection document with those `masterAccounts` having `available` and `enabled` set to true:

```
{
    "_id" : "feature_1_I_want",
    "masterAccounts" : [
        {
            "masterAccountId" : NumberLong(1),
            "available" : true,
            "enabled" : true
        },
        {
            "masterAccountId" : NumberLong(12),
            "available" : false,
            "enabled" : false
        },
        {
            "masterAccountId" : NumberLong(13),
            "available" : false,
            "enabled" : false
        },.......<I would add the MA's here with available true and enabled true>
}
```

I'm not sure what's the best/most efficient way to accomplish this.  I've also attempted to use pipelines, but unclear how they work.  Any advise and guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can  start with below query. It makes `match` at first stage and afterwards it performs the lookup with [nested pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup) by filtering from `betaFeature` collection only documents with `"masterAccounts.available":true` and `masterAccounts.enabled":true`

```
 db.getCollection('maProps').aggregate([
 {$match: {custom_branding: false}},
   {$lookup: 
    {
        from: 'betaFeature',
        let: { beta_id: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$_id",  "$$beta_id" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$masterAccounts.available",  true ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$masterAccounts.enabled",  true ] },
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
              { $project: { _id: 0 } }
              ]
   as: "beta_accounts"}}
 
 
 ])
```